# Processing a very large text file with lazy Texts and ByteStrings

Tags: haskell, text, hashmap, bigdata, file-processing

I'm trying to process a very large unicode text file (6GB+). What I want is to count the frequency of each unique word. I use a strict `Data.Map` to keep track of the counts of each word as I traverse the file.
The process takes too much time and too much memory (20GB+). I suspect the Map is huge but I'm not sure it should reach 5x the size of the file!
The code is shown below. Please note that I tried the following:

- Using `Data.HashMap.Strict` instead of `Data.Map.Strict`. `Data.Map` seems to perform better in terms of slower memory consumption increase rate.
- Reading the files using lazy `ByteString` instead of lazy `Text`. And then I encode it to Text do some processing and then encode it back to `ByteString` for `IO`.

  ```
  import Data.Text.Lazy (Text(..), cons, pack, append)
  import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as T
  import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.IO as TI
  import Data.Map.Strict hiding (foldr, map, foldl')
  import System.Environment
  import System.IO
  import Data.Word

  dictionate :: [Text] -> Map Text Word16
  dictionate = fromListWith (+) . (`zip` [1,1..])

  main = do
      [file,out] <- getArgs
      h <- openFile file ReadMode
      hO <- openFile out WriteMode
      mapM_ (flip hSetEncoding utf8) [h,hO]
      txt <- TI.hGetContents h
      TI.hPutStr hO . T.unlines . 
        map (uncurry ((. cons '\t' . pack . show) . append)) . 
        toList . dictionate . T.words $ txt
      hFlush hO
      mapM_ hClose [h,hO]
      print "success"
  ```

What's wrong with my approach? What's the best way to accomplish what I'm trying to do in terms of time and memory performance?

Comment: How many distinct words are there, roughly, in the file? That should give quite a hint as to whether such high memory consumption is inevitable.

Comment: Are you reading the whole file into memory in order to process it? If so, that explains the high memory usage. Try reading in the file line by line.

Comment: @acfrancis: `Data.Text.Lazy.IO.hGetContents` should certainly get that point right.

Comment: @leftaroundabout let's assume the worst-case, all words in the file are unique. Should the Map size reach 30GB?

Comment: That's surely possible. A tree-like structure such as `Map` has lots of overhead, I'd suspect (assuming x86-64) ~4 machine words per cell, extra two for each `Text`, and finally 1-2 to store the words' characters themselves. Add some total overhead for garbage collection, and 30GB seem not unlikely for hundreds of millions of words.

Comment: @leftaroundabout is there a way to keep parts of this data-structure on disk while still maintaining fast access for the parts currently in-use?

Comment: I suppose it is, but probably quite difficult for a `Map`. If you don't expect much duplicates among the words, perhaps you should completely switch to something else. [External merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting#External_merge_sort) (with duplicate-counting & nubbing as a separate step) is relatively simple. Of course _anything_ external is bound to involve lots of dirty IO; I wager it's actually easier to code this up in C or C++, which also give you much better control over the data structures' overhead.

Comment: Anecdotal supporting evidence: I just ran your program on a 516MB text file, generated by concatenating 512 copies of the text of a book. Memory consumption remained constant at ~16MB; the final output listed 25180 words.

Comment: @duplode That's really weird. What version of GHC are you using and on which architecture? Also are you processing unicode text? I am processing a mix of arabic and english text.

Comment: @leftaroundabout is there anything of this sort already written for Haskell somewhere?

Comment: It's not weird at all, @duplode just used a text file with way less unique words (inevitable for a natural language and not helped by the use of many copies of the _same_ text) than you apparently have in your file.

Comment: 7.6.3, x86-64. Without knowing your input, I guess my results support what leftaroundabout said (my file was made from natural language text, so there are relatively few distinct words).

Comment: I wonder why Data.HashMap is much more slower than Data.Map although it's written on the `unordered-containers` page: "The containers have been optimized for performance critical use, both in terms of large data quantities and high speed".

Comment: Why not try replacing Map then? It ought to be trivial to replace Map with HashMap and easy to replace it with Hashtable.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson I did. That's how I got to know it's much slower :)

Comment: @haskelline Ah, you commented as I wrote mine I think.

Comment: Just to ask the stupid questions: you're compiling with `-O2`, right?

Comment: @DanielWagner: yes, tried both `-O` and `-O2` :)

Comment: You might profit from using something like [`bytestring-trie`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-trie-0.2.3/docs/Data-Trie.html)

Comment: Try finding efficient word count in some other languages and compare. That may give you insight into the problem (i.e. Dictionary has high overhead? Making copies of strings?)

Comment: seconding @J.Abrahamson's suggestion; a trie is at least in theory a much better data structure for this.

Comment: ...oh, and of course the obligatory "what did you learn from profiling?" comment

Comment: Have you considered using a Trie for this?  It's a very good tool for this kind of analysis: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie http://hackage.haskell.org/package/TrieMap   Tries have particular advantages over binary tries or hashmaps for your kind of problem.

Answer (score 7):

This memory usage is expected. `Data.Map.Map` consumes about 6N words of memory + size of keys & values (data taken from [this excellent post by Johan Tibell](http://blog.johantibell.com/2011/06/memory-footprints-of-some-common-data.html)). A **lazy** `Text` value [takes up 7 words + 2*N bytes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-0.11.3.1/docs/src/Data-Text-Lazy-Internal.html#Text) (rounded to the multiple of the machine word size), and a `Word16` [takes up two words](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/GHC-Word.html#Word16) (header + payload). We will assume a 64-bit machine, so the word size will be 8 bytes. We will also assume that the average string in the input is 8 characters long.

Taking this all into account, the final formula for the memory usage is `6*N + 7*N + 2*N + 2*N` words.

In the worst case, all words will be different and there will be about `(6 * 1024^3)/8 ~= 800 * 10^6` of them. Plugging that in the formula above we get the worst-case map size of approx. **102 GiB**, which seems to agree with the experimental results. Solving this equation in the reverse direction tells us that your file contains about `200*10^6` different words.

As for alternative approaches to this problem, consider using a trie (as suggested by J.Abrahamson in the comments) or an approximate method, such as [count-min sketch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count%E2%80%93min_sketch).

Answer (score 0):

In the world of traditional data processing, this problem would have been done by sorting (externally on disk or magtape if needed), then scanning the sorted file to count the grouped-together runs of words.  Of course you could do some partial reductions during the early phases of sorting, to save some space and time.